# How can I get gcc to write a file larger than 2.0 GB?

Tags: compiling, gcc

I wanted to recompile 'xxd' (written in C), so I installed CodeBlocks as the IDE.

All seemed to go well unil I discovered that I couldn't write past the 2.0 GB barrier...

I've read that 'gcc' needs to be recompiled... (That sounds a bit dramatic..)
I've read that I can use 'fread64()' instead of 'fread()' ... (didn't work)
I've read something about a compiler options (?)... but I get lost at that point?

I am surprised that it didn't work out-of-the-box, as I thought the 2.0 GB limit was ancient history as far as defaults go ... wrong again?:(

My OS is 32-bit, on 32-bit hardware.
The gcc version report in as: gcc (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) 4.4.3

Is there a simple way around this issue?

PS.. I was fascinated by the *WARNINGS:* section of  'info xxd' (..only on Linux ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend adding `-D_GNU_SOURCE` as long as `#include <features.h>` is used. This will enable all the largefile support. Read the beginning of `/usr/include/features.h` for more details:

```
...
_LARGEFILE_SOURCE    Some more functions for correct standard I/O.
_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE  Additional functionality from LFS for large files.
_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=N  Select default filesystem interface.
....
_GNU_SOURCE      All of the above, plus GNU extensions.
```

Comment: I assume that this is the best GNU way to go about doing it from a fresh start...(which is where most coding situations 
"start" from).. so it is the best all-round soluton

Answer (score 4):

A simple **#define** *seems* to be all that is needed.. (the program writes past 2 GB now.)

Perhaps the reason it didn't compile apppropriately, is that I compiled a single program from a much larger suite ('xxd' is part of 'vim')...

Had I compiled 'vim' in toto, it would most likely have worked fine...

So for anyone who comes to this page, the following may be of some value:
I assume similar settings would apply to other IDEs.

```
Adding #defines

* Using CodeBocks (as a global setting)
  =====================================
  Settings
    Compiler and Debugger...
      [Compiler Settings]
        [#defines] ... Add the following
         _FILE_OFFSET_BITS="64"

* Using CodeBlocks (for a given Project)
  ======================================
  Properties
    Build Options
      [Compiler Settings]
        [#defines] ... Add the following
         _FILE_OFFSET_BITS="64"

* Directly into gcc's command line
  ================================
  gcc -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS="64"

* Add a #define directly to the source
  ====================================
  #define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS  64
```

---

Also, I discovered this snippet while googling for the solution...
What macros are predefined by gcc? ... in the terminal:

- touch foo.h; cpp -dM foo.h

Comment: Even shorter: `cpp -dM /dev/null`

Comment: cpp -dM <Enter><Ctrl>D ...You got me thinking about what /dev/null adtually does here... and I think I now, also, understand what is happening with cpp.. It must prepend these #defines to all jobs it processes, and in this case the terminal gets tho output instead of the next tool in the pipe; makes sense... There is no magic.. it really is only ones and zeroes... but it surely can look like magic. :) ...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue -- was not able to write a file larger than 2GB.
My OS was 64 bit, mount point was jfs2, and my fsize=-1
All I did was change fopen in my program to fopen64 and voila!

Comment: `fopen` is an alias of `fopen64` on 64-bit platforms.